# File Upload / Download

Tags: ember.js

I have a requirement where I need to upload a file onto server using Ember.JS and similar download a file from server.

Please guide me on the necessary code for this.

I am a newbie with this Framework.

Thanks

Comment: you should start with something, and then when you get stuck post here your problem so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Ember doesn't upload/download files, it's a client side mvc framework. You'll need to use ajax calls for these.

I would suggest using Jquery's ajax library.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for this? It would be really very helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery